# Implementing Checkbox Product Filters ASP.NET MVC - How Can I Pass Data in Collection through URL?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to find a good way to implement product filtering in my ASP.NET MVC application.

[image]

When a user selects a checkbox value, I want to send a key/value pair (or some other type of collection) to my controller where I can then lookup products in my DB that have the filter (like screen size) and value (say 50") and return that list.

Can someone please recommend a good approach for this? **I would like to do this by passing URL parameters so our marketing folks can link to pre-filtered product listing pages.**

I've been researching how to pass an object or collection through the URL but haven't had luck implementing it.

Here is a small example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. User selects "Screen Size - 50"
2. Pass key "size" and value "50" to MVC controller

   ```
    public ActionResult subcategory(string brand, string cat, string cat2, Dictionary<string, string> filters)
   ```
3. Return list of products that have screen size
   of 50", and have checkbox for "Screen Size - 50" checked in View.
4. Allow user to select multiple filters

Note that new products and associated filters (and their categories) will be added in the future. Ideally, the query string will consist of name/value pairs consisting of the category ID and the selected ID, for example

`products/brand/NEC/Pro-Displays/LCD-Monitors?234=43&343=21`

where `234` is the ID for the 'Screen Size' category and `43` is the ID for the '50"' monitor, and `343` is for the 'Brightness' category and `21` is the ID '450 Nit'

For reference, here is how I am rendering the checkbox filters in my View:

```
@for (int x = 0; x < Model.Count(); x++)
{

    <div class="filter-cat" data-target="#list-@x">@Model.ElementAt(x).getName() <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></div>
    <ul id="list-@x">
        @for (int y = 0; y < Model.ElementAt(x).getFilterList().Count; y++)
        {
            <li>
                <input type="checkbox" id="@Model.ElementAt(x).getFilterList().ElementAt(y).getDescription()" name="@Model.ElementAt(x).getFilterList().ElementAt(y).getDescription()" />
                <label for="@Model.ElementAt(x).getFilterList().ElementAt(y).getDescription()">@Model.ElementAt(x).getFilterList().ElementAt(y).getDescription()</label>
            </li>
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: make sure your name for the inputs you want to group together is the same.  this will send the information as an array in a post. and set the value of the checkbox element to "@Model.ElementAt(x).getFilterList().ElementAt(y).getDescription()

Comment: @Fran There's no way to just build a query string with the variables I want to use?

Comment: A `form` method `GET` will "build your query string"

Comment: You not even giving your checkboxes a `value` attribute so nothing will be submitted anyway. And what are the `brand`, `cat` and `cat2` parameters - do you have form controls for them? A `Dictionary` is not the way to go here and you want parameters `string[] size`, `string[] brightness` etc

Comment: @StephenMuecke thanks yes I will add the `value` attribute. I don't want to have to add EVERY possible filter as a parameter - there are many of them. It all depends on what products are being displayed. TVs are going to have screen size and brightness while audio products have filters like impedance and voltage. I want it to all be dynamic.

Comment: The `DefaultModelBinder` does not play will with dictionaries (and you would manually need to create your url so that you have `&filters[0].Key=x&filters[0].Value=y` etc). And you risk exceeding the query string limit and throwing an exception. And how would you expect to handle the case where a user selects both 70" ad 82" screen sizes if i was a dictionary

Comment: @StephenMuecke I see your points - thanks that is good feedback. So how would you handle this then? Not saying I need or want to use a `Dictionary`. It was just what I thought might work. I just don't want to have to write out every possible filter as a parameter that seems like bad design especially because I don't control what filters are in our DB.

Comment: On option could be to create a model (say `class Filters`) containing all the properties - `string[] size` `string[] brightness` etc and then use that model as the parameter to keep the signature of the method small - eg `public ActionResult XXX(Filters model) and then a checked checkbox with `name=size, value="50"` would generate `...&size=50&..` and be bound to your model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke True but if tomorrow my company starts selling drones then a filter for 'Number of Rotors' will show up and then this approach fails because there isn't a property in the `Filters` class for that. I need to pass an arbitrary set of 2 values (like a 2-dim array) for this to work so once I have the Collection in my Controller I can make the DB lookup based on `Screen Size = 20` or whatever it may be

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135907/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-tradez).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to bind back to your `Dictionary<string, string> filters` parameter, you will need to generate inputs in the format

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filters[xxx]" value="yyy" />
```

where `xxx` is the ID of the filter category, and `yyy` is the ID of the selected filter.

Note that since your submitting only the ID values (typeof `int`), then your parameter can be `Dictionary<string, int> filters` (the `Key` still needs to be `string`).

But since you have checkboxes meaning that a user can make multiple selections in a category (and dictionary keys must be unique), you will need a (say) suffix in the `name` attribute to make them unique.

The code in your view is ugly and difficult to read, debug and unit test, so I recommend you start with a view model(s) to represent what you want to display in the view

```
public class ProductFilterVM
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    ... // other properties relating to a product that you may want to display the view - e.g. Description
    public IEnumerable<FilterCategoryVM> FilterCategories { get; set; }
}
public class FilterCategoryVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<FilterSelectionVM> Selections { get; set; }
}
public class FilterSelectionVM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and in your GET method, initialize an instance of `ProductVM` and populate it based on the product being displayed, and return that to the view. The view then becomes

```
@model ProductFilterVM
....
<h2>@Model.Name</h2>
...
<h3>Filters</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm("subcategory", "yourControllerName", FormMethod.Get))
{
    foreach(var category in Model.FilterCategories)
    {
        int counter = 1; // used to generate unique keys
        <h4>@category.Name</h4>
        foreach (var selection in category.Selections)
        {
            string name = String.Format("filters[{0}-{1}]", category.ID, counter++);
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="@name" value="@selection.ID" />
                <span>@selection.Name</span>
            </label>
        }
    }
    <input type="submit" />
}
```

When you submit, the checked checkboxes will be bound to your `filters` parameter, and you will need to parse the `Key` back to an int after removing the suffix

```
public ActionResult subcategory(string brand, ..., Dictionary<string, string> filters)
{
    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, int> item in filters)
    {
        int category = Convert.ToInt32(item.Key.Split('-')[0]);
        int filter = item.Value;
    }
}
```